# Controlling SoundCloud js sdk from Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, soundcloud

I'm trying to control the SoundCloud js sdk from within an angular controller but I'm not sure how to do so. The documentation insists that it be loaded from the script tag:

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
```

But having it in a partial view causes the script not to load. I've tried something that would load the script and add it to the DOM from the controller like this:

```
        function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}

var Initialize = function() {

    SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    });

    SC.get('/tracks', { q: $scope.searchQuery, license: 'cc-by-sa' }, function(tracks) {
        $scope.searchResults = tracks;
        console.log(tracks);
    });
};

loadScript("http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js", Initialize);
```

but Then I wasn't able to access the Player from other methods in the controller.

I've looked into using the http api but it seemed very confusing and that it would be best to use the sdk.

I am pretty new to Angular and completely new to the SoundCloud sdk. Would it be best to bring in Soundcloud as a service? Module? How would I do so?

**My controller**

```
angular.module('RoomCtrl', []).controller('RoomController', function($scope ,$http) {

$scope.tagline = 'the square root of 69 is 8 somethin';

$scope.play = function(id) {
    SC.stream("/tracks/" + id, function(sound){
        sound.play();
    });
}

$scope.searchQuery = "Trophies";

});
```

**My partial**

```
<style>
html                    { overflow-y:scroll; }
body                    { padding-top:50px; }
#todo-list              { margin-bottom:30px; }
</style>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>SoundCloud Player</h1>

<p>{{ tagline }}</p>

<div ng-click="play()">Play TUNES</div>
<div ng-click="pause()">PUASE</div>
</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="searchQuery"/>

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="songs in searchResults" ng-click="play(songs.id)">
    {{songs.title}}
</li>
</ul>
```

**Overall questions:**

How can I be able to use SC anywhere in my controller?

How can I load the sdk without the use of a script tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use Soundcloud as a service, so you can access to the player from everywhere.

When you call to SC.stream you must save that object sound on somewhere, because that object has the methods to stop, pause, resume, events like onfinish and others.

```
This code is working:
$scope.play = function(id){
   SC.stream("/tracks/" + id ,function(sound){
      // Save sound, it holds all the data needed to stop, resume, etc.
      $scope.soundObj = sound;
      sound.play({
      onfinish: function() {              
          //Start a new song or something.
        }
      });
  });
}

$scope.pause = function(){
  $scope.soundObj.pause();
}
```

I know that it's late for this answer, but can help to someone looking for the same thing.